# Unable to update record in textbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am trying to do edit inside grid view. When I click edit button to update record in text box it shows previous record. Please check. I think the error is in Row updating event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fill_grd1();
    }
}

public void fill_grd1()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grd1.DataSource = ds;
        grd1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        grd1.DataSource = null;
        grd1.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();
}

protected void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_insert", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", txtcname.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    fill_grd1();
}

protected void grd1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grd1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    fill_grd1();
}

protected void grd1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse(grd1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_delete", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", id);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    fill_grd1();
}

protected void grd1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TB1 = (TextBox)grd1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("edittxtcname");

    int id = int.Parse(grd1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_update", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", TB1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    grd1.EditIndex = -1;
    fill_grd1();
}

protected void grd1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    grd1.EditIndex = -1;
    fill_grd1();
}

protected void grd1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void grd1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_status_change", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", e.CommandArgument);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    fill_grd1();
}
```

Comment: No, I took - if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fill_grd1();
            }

Comment: `grd1_RowCommand()` occurs before `grd1_RowUpdating()`

Comment: My rowcommand() is changing status -Active to Inactive & rowupdating() is updating the record.What changes I should do?

Comment: All edit/update/select/insert operations pass through RowCommand. one work around is to wrap the code in RowCommand with an `if()`: `if(e.CommandName != "Update" )`  or whatever you need to verify

Comment: Or you can move the status change code to it's own function and call the function, say in `grd1.RowUpdated()` and anyplace that you need to verify status after an editing operation.

Comment: I was using the if statement but it shows -"possible unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison cast the left hand side to type string"

Comment: I was doing -if (e.CommandArgument != "update")
            {

Comment: `CommandArgument` is an `Object` and would need to be cast.  `CommandName` is a string.  But I think you need to use `CommandName` also make sure case is correct

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.